# Socket Programming Python and cURL

Tags: python, sockets, curl

I am trying to build a proxy server in python using my `localhost`
I am using the `request` library to send `post` to another server. So my code works like this:

First we start up the `localhost` server and then the server will listen for any incoming connections. Then the user, in another terminal lets say, can input the following command:

`curl -X POST -d test=testing http://localhost:8000/proxy/http://httpbin.org/post`

My server will output the following:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "POST /proxy/http://httpbin.org/post HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.30.0\r\nHost: localhost:8000\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Length: 9\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\nasdf=blah", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "185", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.12.1"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "209.141.165.165", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

However, the correct output should be this:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "test": "testing"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "9", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.35.0"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "99.250.201.200", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Notice, the `form{}` and `data` fields. So basically, my goal is to get the `-d test=testing` into the `form{}`. Here is my code:

```
import socket, sys,requests
from thread import *

host = ''
port = sys.argv[1] #8000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.bind((host,int(port)))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5)  # Basically a que, number of incoming connections at a time
print("Waiting for connection...")

def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str('Welcome, type your info\n'))
    while True:
        buffer = conn.recv(4096)
        response = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=buffer)
        reply = response.text
        if not reply:
            break
        conn.sendall(str(reply))
        conn.close()


while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('connected to:' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))

    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
```

So right now I have `data = buffer` but it should be something like `form = {'test' : 'testing:}`. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't listen for HTTP connection with a socket. Or did I misunderstand what you are trying to do?

Comment: The "correct output" above implies that you would need to fully parse the HTTP request read from `conn.recv`.  You're just reading the HTTP request into a string.  If you want to separate out individual components, you'll need to parse it.  This will take significant amounts of code if you wish to write it yourself and handle every case.

Comment: Yea, that is what I am doing right now. I thought maybe there was an easier way. New to python but from my experience so far, python has a function for almost everything haha